# powershell to check web template in sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, web-template

I want to check on which webtemplate site is created.
Like for site "xyz/abc.default.aspx" , I want to check on which web templated it was created. Can anyone provide me the powershell command to check same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sitename.com  
write-host "Web Template:" $web.WebTemplate " | Web Template ID:" $web.WebTemplateId 
$web.Dispose()
```